# ShellExecuteEx and getexitcodeprocess

Tags: python, c++, winapi, shellexecuteex

Using ShellExecuteEx(..) to lunch a python script and python script returning a value from python main using sys.exit(0) on success or some other error value. How to read a python script exit code?

After launching application waited to complete script by using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects (...) and then calling GetExitCodeProcess(...) some reason I always read value 1 from getExitCodeprocess(..)

**Python Code:**

```
def main():
    time.sleep(10)   
    logger.info("************The End**********")
    return (15)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

**C++ Code:**

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO rSEI = { 0 };
    rSEI.cbSize = sizeof(rSEI);
    //rSEI.lpVerb = "runas";
    rSEI.lpVerb = "open";
    rSEI.lpFile = "python.Exe";
    rSEI.lpParameters = LPCSTR(path.c_str());
    rSEI.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
    rSEI.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;

    if (ShellExecuteEx(&rSEI))   // you should check for an error here
            ;
        else
            errorMessageID = GetLastError();        //MessageBox("Error", "Status", 0);

        WORD nStatus;
        MSG msg;     // else process some messages while waiting...
        while (TRUE)
        {
            nStatus = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &rSEI.hProcess, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);   // drop through on user activity 

            if (nStatus == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {  // done: the program has ended
                break;
            }

            while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
                //MessageBox("Wait...", "Status", 0);
            }

        }  // launched process has exited

        DWORD dwCode=0;
        if (!GetExitCodeProcess(rSEI.hProcess, &dwCode)) //errorvalue
        {
            DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        }
```

In this code as Python script exiting with 15, I am expecting to read 15 from dwCode from GetExitCodeProcess(rSEI.hProcess, &dwCode)?

Appreciates all of your help on this...

Comment: at first `ShellExecuteEx` here absolute not related (and why not `CreateProcessW` you use ?). if `GetExitCodeProcess` return *true* - in *dwCode* was real code of exit process. another question from which process.. may be "python.Exe" exec child process, where your script run.. about pyton dont know

Comment: Windows will only report that `"python.exe"` ran successfully, but the python module may have failed. Make sure that it's running. Also what's the purpose of `while (PeekMessage...)`?

Comment: The Python code as given will fail because you did not import time or sys, and logger is also undefined. Use CreateProcess to, well, CreateProcess.

Answer (score 0):

1. As the comments metioned, your python script fails.

**Python Code Sample:**

```
import sys
import time
import logging
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger("logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
def main():
    time.sleep(10)  
    logger.info("************The End**********")
    return (15)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

2. Name your Python script file with `.py` as the suffix instead of `.Exe`, such as `"python.py"`
3. Give path value to `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.lpDirectory`, and set `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.lpParameters` to `NULL` here.
   Or Give the path and file combination to `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.lpVerb`, like `"Path\\python.py"`

**C++ Code Sample:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void main()
{
    int errorMessageID = 0;
    std::string path = "Path";
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO rSEI = { 0 };
    rSEI.cbSize = sizeof(rSEI);
    //rSEI.lpVerb = "runas";
    rSEI.lpVerb = "open";
    rSEI.lpFile = "python.py";
    rSEI.lpParameters = NULL;
    rSEI.lpDirectory = path.c_str();
    rSEI.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
    rSEI.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;

    if (!ShellExecuteEx(&rSEI))   // you should check for an error here
        errorMessageID = GetLastError();        //MessageBox("Error", "Status", 0);

    WORD nStatus;
    MSG msg;     // else process some messages while waiting...
    while (TRUE)
    {
        nStatus = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &rSEI.hProcess, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);   // drop through on user activity 

        if (nStatus == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {  // done: the program has ended
            break;
        }

        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            //MessageBox("Wait...", "Status", 0);
        }

    }  // launched process has exited

    DWORD dwCode = 0;
    if (!GetExitCodeProcess(rSEI.hProcess, &dwCode)) //errorvalue
    {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    }
}
```